# Cant run any project on Android studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

When ever I open my android studio it show some errors are folows

```
Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+
<a href="install.m`enter code here`2.repo">Install Repository and 
sync project</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">
Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

Comment: most likely you're missing the `google()` repository in the `build.gradle`.

Comment: It show me an error like:                                                                                   
                                                                                                                   
Error:(6, 0) Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container.
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\H.M.Thaheed\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\build.gradle">Open File</a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your top level build.gradle file, add google as a repository

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        // If you're using a version of Gradle lower than 4.1, you must instead use:
        // maven {
        //     url 'https://maven.google.com'
        // }
        // An alternative URL is 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'
    }
}
```

Comment: It show me an error like: Error:(6, 0) Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container. <a href="openFile:C:\Users\H.M.Thaheed\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\build.gradle">Open File</a>

Comment: you might be using gradle lower than v4.1, please see the comment. use maven {url...} instead of google()

Comment: After inserting it reduces some errors but it arose more errors like     Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Error: more than one library with package name 'android.support.graphics.drawable'

Answer (score -1):

update your android studio with all your dependencies and create a new project

Comment: After update my android studio I got the same error which I mentioned     Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. > Error: more than one library with package name 'android.support.graphics.drawable'

Comment: this can't be. you're missing something out. its either you're trying to reload a corrupted project instead of creating a new one or you are not providing the full description. updating all dependencies should work for you 99.9%  :D